# C# sorting an array of chars without the use of a method

Tags: c#

I have an array of structs of people. Each one of these guys has a parameter string for name and a string for surname. And now I have to sort the array and write it out by checking each character. And if there are two persons with the same name, I have to check the each character of their surnames too.
So lets say we have:

JOHN DOE
JOHN ABCD

The output would be
JOHN ABCD
JOHN DOE

This is what I've got so far:

```
string abeceda = "ABCČDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSŠTUVZŽabcčdefghijklmnoprsštuvzž";

char[] poljelegalnihznakov = new char[abeceda.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < abeceda.Length;i++)
{
    char c=abeceda[i];
    poljelegalnihznakov[i] = c;
}

for (int i = 0; i < stevilodelavcev; i++)
{
    string imedelavca = delavcipolje[i].ime;
    char[] ime = SortirajDelovnoStevilko(imedelavca);
}
```

The abeceda string is basically all the chars of my countries alphabet. I'm not sure I will use this array of chars but I just wrote it out.

How would we sort this without the use of array.sort() or such other methods?(since I'm not allowed to use any easy functions...).

This is my struct:

```
public struct delavci
{
    public string delovnastevilka;
    public string priimek;
    public string ime;
    public int delovnadoba;
    public int starost;


    public delavci(string delovnastevilka, string priimek, string ime, int delovnadoba, int starost)
    {
        this.delovnastevilka = delovnastevilka;
        this.priimek = priimek;
        this.ime = ime;
        this.delovnadoba = delovnadoba;

        this.starost = starost;
    }

}
```

Comment: use `OrderBy` in lambda expressions; study this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/afenster/lambda-expressions-are-wonderful/

Comment: We're not allowed the use of lambdas.... or order by's..

Comment: is this your school home work?

Comment: Yeah someone really wants us to know how array.sort source code works

Comment: Google sorting algorithms.

Comment: Didn't SO have a `Homework` or `Schoolwork` tag at one time?  Anyway, we don't do school work for you.

Comment: If you really want to know how `Array.Sort` works, here ya go. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,a26f9995088379ee . I know you didn't mean it literally, but it's still informative to look at. Also, as 500 mentioned, if can search for it: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20sorting%20algorithms

Comment: As a side note, you should try and write your code in English on SO. All these 15 characters long Slovenian (I guess) words make it really hard to digest.